# I need to replace a square bracketed range with a variable range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that puts s formula into a two-dimensional range and correctly adds the relative addresses. However the range is "hard-coded" and I need to be able to define the depth of the range programicly. My code uses square brackets to set the range and it seems that you can't use a variable inside square brackets (or at least I can't figure out how to do so)

I need the code to use a variable to define the bottom right hand corner of the range. I Ideas would be most helpful.

I want to replace `[T3:DX321].Formula` with something like `["T3:DX" & Lastrow].Formula...`

NOTE the three named ranges in the code each refer to a single column of data.

```
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Lastrow = BillSch.Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row ' Last row of BillSch
        
        'This code works but I need the lastrow of DX to be a variable
        [T3:DX321].Formula = "=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(1,(BS_ORDERNO=$S3)*(BS_WEEKNO=T$1),BS_CHARGEDPRICE),"""")"

'       These two attempts were failures
'        [T3:DX" & lastrow].Formula = "=IFERROR...."  'ERROR--  "Runtime error 434 Object required

'        Dim Rng As Range
'        Rng = BillSch.Range("T3:DX" & Lastrow)  'ERROR--  "Object variable or With block variable not set"
'        Rng.Formula = "=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(1,(BS_ORDERNO=$S3)*(BS_WEEKNO=T$1),BS_CHARGEDPRICE),"""")"
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use `Set`:  eg `Set Rng =..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Reference a Range

- You forgot to use the ***Set*** keyword as mentioned by Ron Rosenfeld in the comments:

  ```
  Set rng = BillSch.Range("T3:DX" & LastRow)
  ```
- BTW, you don't want to use `[T3:DX321]` ever since it means the **risky** `ActiveSheet.Range("T3:DX321")` opposed to the **safe** `BillSch.Range("T3:DX321")`.
- Here are just a few other ways how to tackle this.

**Hard Coded (Last Row)**

```vb
Dim rng As Range, LastRow As Long

With BillSch
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("T3", .Cells(LastRow, "DX"))
End With
```

**Hard Coded**

```vb
Dim rng As Range

With BillSch.Range("S3")
    Set rng = .Resize(BillSch.Cells(BillSch.Rows.Count, .Column) _
        .End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1).EntireRow.Columns("T:DX")
End With
```

**Dynamic (Constants)**

```vb
Const FIRST_CELL As String = "S3"
Const RANGE_COLUMNS As String = "T:DX"

Dim rng As Range

With BillSch.Range(FIRST_CELL)
    Set rng = .Resize(BillSch.Cells(BillSch.Rows.Count, .Column) _
        .End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1).EntireRow.Columns(RANGE_COLUMNS)
End With
```

- The latter is the basis for creating a function...

```vb
Function GetRangeEnd( _
    ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
    ByVal LastRowFirstCellAddress As String, _
    ByVal RangeColumnsAddress As String) _
As Range

    If ws Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    Dim rg As Range, rCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range(LastRowFirstCellAddress)
        rCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If rCount < 1 Then Exit Function ' no data in column range
        Set GetRangeEnd = .Resize(rCount).EntireRow.Columns(RangeColumnsAddress)
   End With

End Function
```

... which you could utilize with

```
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = GetRangeEnd(BillSch, "S3", "T:DX")
```

Answer (score 0):

- `[..]` in your code is equalent to `Evaluate("..")`. It's better to use `Range(..)` object.

```vb
    Range("T3:DX" & Lastrow).Formula = "=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(1,(BS_ORDERNO=$S3)*(BS_WEEKNO=T$1),BS_CHARGEDPRICE),"""")"
```